# Store load callback

Tags: extjs, callback, load, store, records

Why this code:

```
var store = Ext.create('cp.store.form.MedicoEspecialidad',{});
    store.load({
        params: {idUsuario: idUsuario},
        callback: function(r,option,success){
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
```

Shows "r" how "null" when the php script (specify in the store url) return the next json:

> {"success":true,"total":6,"data":[{"idEspecialidad":1,"especialidad":"Oftalmolog\u00eda","checked":false},{"idEspecialidad":2,"especialidad":"Pediatr\u00eda","checked":false}]}

Any ideas ?.

Comment: Can you include the definition of `cp.store.form.MedicoEspecialidad`? More specifically, the proxy of the store?

Comment: Looks like your proxy reader does not recognize data coming from PHP script. I would go into `Ext.data.reader.Reader`'s `read` method and set a debug log in there to see what is going on.